# Search parameters SQLSRV_QUERY for WHERE IN syntax

Tags: php, sql, parameter-passing, sqlsrv

I wonder if there is a way to pass some values into the parameters option on the `sqlsrv_query` function. I tried a few things but could not get it to work.

This query is what I want to be executed:

```
SELECT id, name, etc
FROM sqlTable
WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '100', '314')
```

I want to pass the `WHERE IN` values using the params option, like this:

```
$q = "SELECT id FROM sqlTable WHERE id IN ?";
$p = array(array('1', '2', '100', '314'));
sqlsrv_query($connection, $q, $p);
```

Right now I'm passing the values directly into the query string, but for obvious security reasons I want to pass them as parameters into the function.
Anyone any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out this issue on the sql side. Now I pass a comma separated string with the ids to the query using the params in the `sqlsrv_query()` function. The query sets the string in a temporarily variable. Using a splitting function every id is stored in a temporarily table. As last I `JOIN` the temporarily table with the table from witch I want to get the results.

Splitting function in SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

PHP code and SQL query:

```
$q = "
DECLARE @inStr varchar(max)
SET @inStr = ?

DECLARE @tmpTable table (tmpID varchar(200))

INSERT @tmptable (tmpID)
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@inStr)

SELECT id, name, etc
FROM sqlTable
JOIN @tmpTable ON id = tmpID";
$p = array('1,2,100,314');
sqlsrv_query($connection, $q, $p);
```

Comment: Why not just create a stored procedure altogether and execute it with string parameter in PHP? The enduring debate in SQL: [parameterized query vs stored procedure](https://www.google.com/#q=parameterized+queries+vs+stored+procedure).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [PDO binded parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) which you can pass a defined array in `execute()`. However, you would need to prepare the statement, knowing number of `IN()` clause items in advance.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;database=$database",$username,$password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlTable WHERE id IN (:first, :second, :third, :fourth)";    
    $STH = $dbh->prepare($sql);    
    $nums = array('1', '2', '100', '314');
    $STH->execute($nums);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

Comment: That is also possible with the Microsoft SQL Server Driver. I was actually hoping on a cleaner solution where you could simply state `IN(:first)` and pass an array or string with all the clause values in it.

Comment: Parameters need placeholders. You have to prepare in advance its structure. And this would arguably be the *cleaner* version. How can one bind values to an indeterminate number of elements?